# Getting guid in sandcastle chm with presentation style vs2010

Tags: chm, sandcastle

I use Sandcastle to generate chm files for my dll's, but i want to use the VS2010 presentation style.

When i build the chm file with VS2005 presentation style, the 'Usage Note' of a method looks like this:

```
Usage Note
In Visual Basic and C#, you can call this method as an instance method on any 
object of type Object. When you use instance method syntax to call this method, 
omit the first parameter. For more information, see 
Extension Methods (Visual Basic) or Extension Methods (C# Programming Guide).
```

where the text 'Extention Methods (Visual Basic)' and 'Extension Methods (C# Programming Guide)' both are links to MSDN sites.

But when i use the VS2010 presentation style (and this is the only property i did change), i get this:

```
Usage Note
In Visual Basic and C#, you can call this method as an instance method on any
object of type Object. When you use instance method syntax to call this method,
omit the first parameter. For more information, see
[b8020aae-374d-46a9-bcb7-8cc2390b93b6] or [175ce3ff-9bbf-4e64-8421-faeb81a0bb51].
```

So no links, but Guids.
Question is how to get the links in the VS2010 style just as in the VS2005 style.